# Opensplice support

Tags: ros, ros2, dds, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question is if ros2 has support for Adlink Opensplice lib and what extend?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323261/opensplice-support/) by [brkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4761/brkk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2019-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My question is if ros2 has support for Adlink Opensplice lib

OpenSplice is indeed a supported DDS vendor in ROS 2. The RMW layer is hosted at [ros2/rmw_opensplice](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_opensplice).

> and what extend?

Looking at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_opensplice/issues) it would appear there are a nr of outstanding issues.

REP 2000 lists OpenSplice support as "Tier 2" for Crystal ([here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#crystal-clemmys-december-2018-december-2019)), which implies that OpenSplice does not see the same level of support as FastRTPS or RTI Connext (the exact difference between the various tiers should get clarified by [ros-infrastructure/rep#192](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/192)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4761/brkk/) on 2019-05-16**:
Thanks for the answer from the latest commits to the infrastructure I see that they are changing the definition of Tier 2 support so we might get better packages than the ad hoc binaries. what surprises me that open splice implementation is not supported for Debian based platforms which is my current system right now and it is kind of working (with some performance issues though).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-16**:
"support" is a bit ambiguous of course: at one level it may mean that there is a way to use OpenSplice as your middleware, which is what the RMW repository makes possible. But then there are things like non-functional requirements and whether you receive the same kind of support when reporting issues.

The fact that it works for you on Debian doesn't necessarily mean that it makes sense to state that (in REP 2000 fi), as it may still be too costly or involved to actually support it properly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works well enough for us to run the navigation stack with a turtlebot 3 in gazebo, although we haven't tried running across multiple machines.

It has different problems than the FastRTPS implementation, but it doesn't seem worse for our use cases.

---

Originally posted by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) with karma: 303 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4761/brkk/) on 2019-05-16**:
Well yes it works but what we found is it has some performance issues and  higher resource usage (especially CPU) than the Fast-RTPS do you know the in which configuration you used it, what is the Qos settings?